# AJAX Response Not displaying on the page

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to have the table in my view expand into a detail row. The expand function is working, and getting the data is working. However, the detail table that I'm trying to display is not showing up. The html on the view looks something like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr><td>Column 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Column 3</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   foreach(var data in ViewData["data"] as List<DataModel>)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@data.Data1</td>
        <td>@data.Data2</td>
        <td>@data.Data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="6">
            <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="@data.MembershipId">
                <div id="UpdatePanel_@data.MembershipId" class="container">

                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>           
    }      
</tbody>
</table>
```

Then I have the JQuery using the @data.MembershipId to get the data for the detail table:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var memberId;
    $('.header').click(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(50);
        memberId = $(this).data("target").replace("#", "");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "GetActivity",
            data: { membershipId: memberId },
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: OnError
        });
    });
    function OnSuccess(data) {
        var TableContent = "<table>" +
            "<thead>" +
            "<tr>" +
            "<td>Detail Column 1</td>" +
            "<td>Detail Column 2</td>" +
            "<td>Detail Column 3</td>" +
            "<td>Detail Column 4</td>" +
            "<td>Detail Column 5</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "</thead>" +
            "<tbody>";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            TableContent += "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + data[i].data1 + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + data[i].data2 + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + data[i].data3 + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + data[i].data4 + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + data[i].data5 + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
        }
        TableContent += "</tbody></table>";
        $("#UpdatePanel_" + memberId).html(TableContent);
    }
    function OnError(data) {
        alert("Error: " + data)
    }
});
```

The JQuery AJAX call goes to my Controller to get the SQL Data and gets a List of the Data Model. The data returns correctly, and if I inspect the page, I'm seeing the table built with the data correctly, but it's not displaying anything when I expand the table row.

I don't think this is a problem with the CSS, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I think `memberId` on `onSuccess` function makes this problem .. you can use `function OnSuccess(data , memberId)` and on ajax `success: function(data){onSuccess(data , memberId)}`

Comment: Are you sure that this selector exist `"#UpdatePanel_" + memberId` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it can work.  I am a tutor on tutors-live, code mentor, Wyzant, and Chegg.  Perhaps I can help you with programming.  Please mark my answer as correct, as it works.  If we can work together, we can improve your coding, such as instead of ViewState, you should use a model.

Anyhow,

Here is the view

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Tut126</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .customCSS {
            border: 3px solid #f00;
        }

        .header {
            border: 3px solid #4cff00;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Display(arg) {
            $("#" + arg.id).collapse('toggle');
        }
        $(function () {
            var memberIds;
            $('.header').click(function () {
                //header column look like column so we don't need all the children
                //$(this).nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(50);
                $(this).slideToggle(50);
                //memberId = $(this).data("target").replace("#", "");
                memberIds = $(".customCSS");
                var elements = [];
                memberIds.each(function () {
                    elements.push(this.id);
                });
                var stringOfElementIDs = elements.toString();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetActivity", "Home")',
                    data: { membershipIds: stringOfElementIDs },
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    error: OnError
                });
            });
            function OnSuccess(data) {
                var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(dataObj, function (i, anObj) {
                    var TableContent = "<table>" +
                   "<thead>" +
                   "<tr>" +
                   "<td>Detail Column 1</td>" +
                   "<td>Detail Column 2</td>" +
                   "<td>Detail Column 3</td>" +
                   "<td>Detail Column 4</td>" +
                   "<td>Detail Column 5</td>" +
                   "</tr>" +
                   "</thead>" +
                   "<tbody>";
                    TableContent += "<tr>";
                    $.each(anObj.outData, function (index, val) {
                        TableContent += "<td>" + val + "</td>";
                    });
                    TableContent += "</tr>";
                    TableContent += "</tbody></table>";
                    $("#" + anObj.id).html(TableContent);
                });
            }
            function OnError(data) {
                alert("Error: " + data)
            }
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            Click in the header to get activity
            <tr class="header">
                <td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 2</td>
                <td>Column 3</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var data in ViewData["data"] as List<Testy20161006.Controllers.DataModel>)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@data.DataColumn1</td>
                    <td>@data.DataColumn2</td>
                    <td>@data.DataColumn3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="6">
                        Click in the red row to expand
                        <div class="accordion-body collapse customCSS container" id="@data.MembershipId" onclick="Display(this)">
                            ...some text1...
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code

```
    public string GetActivity(string membershipIds)
    {
        List<ReturnValue> returnVals = new List<ReturnValue>();
        var listOfMembershipIds = membershipIds.Split(',');

        foreach (string id in listOfMembershipIds)
        {
            List<string> toArrayOut = new List<string>();
            toArrayOut.Add("Data1");
            toArrayOut.Add("Data2");
            toArrayOut.Add("Data3");
            toArrayOut.Add("Data4");
            toArrayOut.Add("Data5");
            ReturnValue returnVal = new ReturnValue { id = id, outData = toArrayOut };
            returnVals.Add(returnVal);
        }

        //I NUGETed the JSON Newtonsoft program
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnVals);
        return serialized;
    }

    public ActionResult Tut126()
    {
        List<DataModel> listOfDataModel = new List<DataModel>();
        DataModel d1 = new DataModel { DataColumn1 = "Data101", DataColumn2 = "Data102", DataColumn3 = "103", MembershipId = "dataMembershipId1" };
        DataModel d2 = new DataModel { DataColumn1 = "Data201", DataColumn2 = "Data202", DataColumn3 = "203", MembershipId = "dataMembershipId2" };
        listOfDataModel.Add(d1);
        listOfDataModel.Add(d2);
        ViewData["data"] = listOfDataModel;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me to where I needed to go.